# Create a fading list

Tags: html, css

My goal here is to create a list where the text of the first `<li>` is almost white (`#CCC`) and every `<li>` after this gets darker.
The last `<li>` should be almost black (or at almost 0% opacity).

The idea is to create a kind of fading text effect **without Javascript**.

I have tried to add an overlay div with a gradient background using opacity to progressively hide the text, but these problems happened :

- The gradient does not reach 0% opacity inside the main div. This is because it's height is not the same as the main div's height. As the main div can change height (I'm planning to dynamically add some `<li>`), I can't set the height of the overlay to a fixed size.
- As the gradient is on top of the `<ul>`, I can't select the text inside the `<li>`.

Moreover, the padding of the `<li>` makes the `<li>` overflow on the right. Since the width of the main `<div>` will be in percent instead of pixels in the end, I can't set the width to a fixed size either.

Here is my code (snippet didn't show the gradient) with some explanations about the issues :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Fading overlay test</title>
        <style>
body{
    background-color: black;
    color: #ccc;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.fade_test{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 300px;
    max-height: 570px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

.fade_test ul{
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.fade_test li{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #0000FF;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .61em;
}

.fading_overlay{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fade_test">
            <ul>
                <li>Line n°1. Because of the padding, we can't see the blue right border. &#8594;</li>
                <li>Line n°2. The overlay is on top of this text. Therefore, we cannot select this text.</li>
                <li>Line n°3</li>
                <li>Line n°4</li>
                <li>Line n°5</li>
                <li>Line n°6</li>
                <li>Line n°7</li>
                <li>Line n°8</li>
                <li>Line n°9</li>
                <li>Line n°10</li>
                <li>Line n°11</li>
                <li>Line n°12. This is at the bottom of the ".fade_test". This should be almost 100% black (we shouldn't be able to read this).</li>
                <li>Line n°13. This one is invisible (it overflows), it's a desired behaviour.</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="fading_overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to use color to fade the text but couldn't figure a way to do the fading part. I also have tried to mess with height, width, position, float, opacity and even calc() but none worked.
The code is the closest I got to what I want so far.

The code doesn't need to be IE compatible and can use the latest CSS techniques available. I just don't want to use Javascript (if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your first Problem with the Height of the overlaying div, you could add `position: relative;` to `.fade_test` and change `position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%` to `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;` in class `.fading_overlay`

To fix the problem with the overlay blocking interactions with the list items you could add `pointer-events: none;` to the overlays class. This will make all pointer-events (e.g. mouse clicks and so on) go through.

To fix the Problem with the `li` padding just add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.fade_test li`

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9sf4ahLv/7/)

Comment: I didn't know `pointer-events`. Thank you for your answer, it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad i could help!